# Change in height when taking "a step" in the direction of steepest descent.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tutor people in a variety of math subjects, but had a Calc III question come up that I could not remember quite how to do, nor could I find a reference to check.

> Suppose you are standing on a hill given by $h(x,y)=-x^2-y^2-10$, at the point $(1,1,8)$. If you take a step in the direction of steepest descent, where do you end up, as a point $(x,y,h)$

I know the direction of steepest descent is the negative of the gradient, I know that "a step" is taken to mean a differential step, but just the last bit, to find how far you actually move down the hill when you move a differential step in that direction, has got me.

Comment: Taking a differential step would move you down a differential amount, which would amount to nothing.  The rate you are moving down (differential amount down divided by differential step), however, is the magnitude of the gradient.

Comment: I would have thought it obvious that I wanted the relationship between the differentials. I.e, if I move to $(1+dx, 1+dy,h)$, how can I express that h?